# Creating manifold from subsets?

Tags: manifolds

In the definition of Manifold, we are given countable atlases $(U_i, \psi_i)$, such that every point $p$ is contained in one such $U_i$ and $\psi_i(U_i)$ is homeomorphic to some subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now I want to reverse this process. Suppose I choose a countable subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and also assume I specify the individual intersection between any two subsets. Now I move around those subsets to satisfy the intersection rule I specified above, then will the resultant figure be a manifold. Also, can every manifold be deconstructed and then reconstructed in the way I mentioned.

Note:

(1) I am allowed to work in higher $\mathbb{R}^n$, as I figured the intersection that I specified might be unattainable in lower dimension but possible in a higher dimension (I will further clarify on this remark if needed. Let me know in the comment).

(2) The subsets are of the same dimension. For example, a circle has dimension 1 because it is essentially a length, the disk has dimension 2 because it is an area and so on.

Comment: Your question lacks context and rigour. But I think Exercise 5, page 14 of Hirsch, Differential Topology may be related.

Comment: @Laz Yeah that question does sort of look similar to my line of thinking. Out of curiosity, how did you recall this particular problem which was buried in a 200 page book. Seeing you, I am really feeling inadequate.

Comment: I just remember virtually every exercise I solve. I guess that in this particular case is because I really like Hirsch's book.